# My website hosts various m4a files but they do not play in Internet Explorer

Tags: html5, internet-explorer, audio

I've got an m4a file that loads properly in all browsers, except for Internet Explorer (no surprise). The error is: "Invalid source".

My HTML5 code looks like this:

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="../music/music.m4a" type="audio/aac">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

I have also tried replacing the extension `aac` with `m4a`, like so:

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="../music/lasthymn.m4a" type="audio/m4a">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Unfortunately, this still returns the "Invalid source" error... how can we fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the issue by using the following HTML5 markup:

```
<audio src="music.m4a" controls></audio>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem would seem to be that you are specifying an unsupported/invalid mime-type in the `type` attribute. (See [IE audio object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff975061%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) - Scroll down for the supported mime-types.)

If this is AAC in an MP4 container then the correct mime-type should probably be `audio/mp4`.

Internet Explorer does not appear to be able to handle an incorrect mime-type, whereas other browsers are far more tolerable. In fact Chrome seems to be able to play the media regardless of what "type" you try to say it is.